# when I run my model.py , it said OSError: no file with expected extension , but i have put the .so file under the same folder

Tags: python, pytorch

This is my code:

```
dll = np.ctypeslib.load_library('render_balls_so', '.')
```

And I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/name/Documents/PointNet/show_3d_ball.py", line 22, in 
> dll = np.ctypeslib.load_library('render_balls_so', '.')   File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 155, in load_library
> raise OSError("no file with expected extension") OSError: no file with expected extension

Comment: I think you need to mention the extension. Try it with render_balls_so.so .

Comment: The docs say that the `libname` is without extension.  Make sure you have the `render_balls_so.so` in the same folder where you *run the script*. The `.` means "this folder" and it is relative to cwd. Or, change the cwd or the argument accordingly. For debugging, you could try to print out `os.path.dirname('.')` and see if it contains "render_balls_so.so".

Comment: @NiteyaShah: Extension doesn't need to be mentioned, although file needs to contain the extension.